# Is it better to assign a name to a throwaway object in Python, or not?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is not a "why doesn't my code run" question. It is a "how / why does my code work" question. I am looking to generalize from this specific case to learn what broad rules apply to similar situations in the future.

I have done some searching (Google and StackOverflow) for this, but haven't seen anything that answers this question directly. Of course, I'm not entirely sure how best to ask this question, and may be using the wrong terms. I welcome suggested edits for the question title and labels.

I have the following function (which makes use of the [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/) module):

```
def make_session(username,password,login_url):
#The purpose of this function is to create a requests.Session object,
#update the state of the object to have all of the cookies and other
#session data necessary to act as a logged in user at a website, and
#return the session to the calling function.

    new_session = requests.Session()

    login_page = new_session.get(login_url)

    #The function get_login_submit_page takes the previously
    #created login_page, extracts the target of the login form
    #submit, and returns it as a unicode string.

    submit_page_URL = get_login_submit_page_URL(login_page)

    payload = {u'session_name': username, u'session_password': password}

    new_session.post(submit_page_URL,data=payload,allow_redirects=True)

    return new_session
```

And what I really want to know is whether or not how I do this line matters:

```
new_session.post(submit_page_URL,data=payload,allow_redirects=True)
```

According to the requests documentation, the Session.post method returns a Response object.

However, this method also has side-effects which update the Session object. It is those side effects that I care about. I have no use for the Response object this method creates.

I have tested this code in practice, both assigning the Response to a label, and leaving it as presented above. Both options appear to work equally well for my purposes.

The actual question I am asking is: since, reasonably, whether I assign a label or not, the Requests object created by my call to Session.post falls out of scope as soon as the Session is returned to the calling function, does it matter whether I assign a label or not?

Rather, do I save any memory/processing time by not making the assignment? Do I create potential unforeseen problems for myself by not doing so?

Comment: I don't see why we need a reference to an object which is used only once.

Comment: Martijjn Pieters's answer is correct, and it responds to your question as you asked it. Anyway, I would suggest that you do use the return value to perform error detection (either checking its status_code manually or calling its raise_for_status() method).

Comment: @tawmas Thank you for the feedback, I was thinking about that as well. I realize there is a lot of room for improvement in this function (and the rest of the program, not shared). For development practice. I keep a running list of these things as I make note of them. There is a fine line to walk between doing things the 'right way' / building good habits, and overengineering simple one-off scripts that will never see the light of day, which I try to keep in mind. My income is not derived from programming in any way at this time.

Comment: @thefourtheye Thank you - this seems to support the answer accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are not using the return value of a call, there is little point in assigning it to a local name.

The returned response object will then not be referenced anywhere and freed two bytecodes earlier than if you assigned it to a name, and ignored that name before returning from the function.

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question - it is better not to assign a local name if I am never using the return of the call (as a general rule). I am a little confused by your wording "freed two bytecodes earlier", could you clarify what you meant?

Comment: @selllikesybok: The Python interpreter loop executes bytecodes; if you assigned the return value to a name, that'd be one extra bytecode to execute. You return the function directly after the assignment, at which point all locals would be unbound, the ref count for the response object would drop to 0 and it would be freed then, instead of right after the `new_session.post()` call returned.